# Ruby on Rails My Database always makes the foreign keys nil why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

This is my schema for Table Listing

```
create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.text "description"
  t.string "city"
  t.string "state"
  t.string "zipcode"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "category_id"
  t.integer "subcategory_id"
end
```

Here is my Model:

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category, required: false
  belongs_to :subcategory, required: false
end
```

Every time I enter a data via form, My data are recorded in Database with their assigned values but my foreign keys (category_id, subcategory_id) are always nil? why?

Here is my form: new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <p>  <%= f.label :category_id %>
  <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map {|f| [f.name,f.id]} %></p>
  <p>  <%= f.label :subcategory_id %>
  <%= f.select :subcategory_id, Subcategory.all.map {|f| [f.name,f.id]} %></p>
  <%= f.label :city %>
  <%= f.text_field :city %>
  <%= f.label :state %>
  <%= f.text_field :state %>
  <%= f.label :zipcode %>
  <%= f.text_field :zipcode, class: "zip-width", maxlength: "5" %>
  <%= f.submit class:"create-button" %> 
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    @societal = @categories[0] #id 1 bhayekoharu
    @onsale = @categories[1]
    @housing = @categories[2]
    @works = @categories[3]
    @services = @categories[4]
    @personal = @categories[5]
  end

  def show
    @listings =  Listing.where(category_id: params[:id])

  end
```

My database shows following record:

```
    <Listing id:6, title: "apartment on rent", description: "rent 5 bed room\r\n800 per month\r\nno pets", city: "aust
        in", state: "tx", zipcode: "78749", created_at: "2018-06-21 00:02:40", updated_at: "2018-06-21 00:02:40
        ", category_id: nil, subcategory_id: nil>,

Here is my full controller for Listing:

class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  def create # we have to hold paramaters.
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
    if @listing.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
  # redisplay the form if validation failed
    render action: 'new'
    end
  end


  def show
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(:title, :description, :city, :state, :zipcode,:category, :subcategory) 
  end
```

end

Comment: can you add your form code to your question?

Comment: And what does your controller look like? May as well include the `params` from your logs as well.

Comment: Please add controller method for create and strong params as well I think you must be missing above fields.

Comment: Also, post the params you are gettinng on form submit from the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common mistake you might've done is not allowing those `ids` in strong params. Check the strong params in your controller where the `listing create action` is residing.

You should permit `category_id` and `subcategory_id` in `strong params`.

Example:

```
def listing_params
  params.require(:listing).permit(:category_id, :subcategory_id)
end
```

If you're sure that you're allowing both the parameters, Please share your Rails log.

Comment: I did more silly mistake, in my strong parameters I sent: category, subcategory instead of category_id and subcategory_id. Now it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to permit your Params at your controller. Permit both at param.require and It will work.